# Jquery document click hide for touch device

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).delegate('#btn', 'click', function(){
    $('#drop').show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(){
    $('#drop').hide();
});

<span id="btn">click me</span>
<div id="drop"></div>
```

I have a button when it clicked, it will show div, when user click document, div will hide.

It works fine on desktop but touch device.

Anyone know how to make it works for touch device?

Comment: Use this `$(document).on('click touchstart', function () {`

Comment: cool, it works now, can u post on answer so i can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger the function with click or touch, you could try this:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function () {
```